# Allow only 1 letter and unlimited numbers in input

Tags: html, regex

So, banging my head on the wall with a regex test site and can't seem to nail this one down.

Trying to make it so an HTML  is validated to only allow 1 letter maximum, but unlimited numbers, no other characters.

W123 = valid

124X = valid

1234 = valid

WW12 = invalid

Comment: Maybe something like `[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]?[0-9]*`

Comment: @BankBuilder `{0,1}` is usually written as `?` to mean "optional"

Comment: Is the empty string allowed ? or a string that is only one letter ? In other words, do you need at least one digit?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte ah I should have specified, yes I believe 1 digit is required, while 1 letter is optional

Comment: It's amazing the ability I have to ask good questions! I think it's due to my regular sports practice and my consumption of nettle soup.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing incredible here, only two possible cases:

- the string starts with a digit
- the string doesn't start with a digit

In the two scenari only one letter is allowed.

To express that you need a group and an alternation:

```
^(?:\d+[A-Z]?|[A-Z]\d)\d*$
```

In the two branches stored inside the group, you can see that there's at least one digit (in the first because I used the `+` quantifier, in the second because of `\d`). The first branch matches any string that starts with a digit with and without a letter (because of the optional letter `[A-Z]?`), the second one matches strings that start with a letter. `\d*` at the end of the pattern matches remaining digits.
Obviously the pattern is enclosed between anchors for the start `^` and the end of the string `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You  look for zero or more digits followed by a letter followed by zero or more digits or alternatively at least one digit.

```
^\d*[a-zA-Z]\d*$|^\d+$
```

Comment: Maybe, I would expect just a letter to be valid as well. But depends on whether unlimited numbers are required or optional.

Comment: I see, you are right.